# Is it true that any non-solvable group cannot be a subgroup of a solvable group?

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

There is a theorem that states every subgroup of a solvable group is solvable. Does this imply that if a group is not solvable then it cannot be a subgroup of any solvable group? For instance, $S_5$ is not a subgroup of any solvable group. That seems like a strong claim, so I just want to make sure I understand this correctly.

If this is true, does this have other implications/applications?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: In order to prove this statement, just follow the definition; there is not much else to it.

Comment: Its an immediate consequence of the theorem you stated. In general if $p \Rightarrow q$ is true then $ \neg q\Rightarrow \neg p$ is also true.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144812/subgroups-of-finite-solvable-groups-solvable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that follows from the (fairly) well-known result that solvability is hereditary.

This is an example of the *contrapositive*.  (So your question is an easy one.)

That's if a subgroup of a group is not solvable,  then we would have that the parent group can't be solvable.

---

As far as consequences,  note that since $A_5\le S_n $ for $n\gt4$, we get that such $S_n $ are not solvable.  For $A_5$ is not solvable.

This is the key step in the Abel-Ruffini theorem,  that there's no closed form for solving quintic polynomials and those of higher degree.

---

Note that as a special case  we get the statement that a finite abelian group can't have a non-solvable subgroup.